# How to convert characters from Hiragana to Katakana

Tags: javascript, html, cjk

I am working on a project where I have code that converts English syllables into their Japanese counterparts (Hiragana). This works like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/wanakana"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="typeshere" placeholder="Type here or click buttons"></textarea>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="convert('ん')">
                    <div>ん</div>
                    <div>n</div>
                </td>
                <td onclick="convert('わ')">
                    <div>わ</div>
                    <div>wa</div>
                </td>
        </table>
    <button>Convert</button>
    <script>
        /* typing input */
        var input = document.getElementById('typeshere');
        wanakana.bind(input);
        /* button input */
        function convert(x) {
            input.value += x;
            input.focus();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I need be able to also switch to the other Japanese alphabet (Katakana), but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's the things I am trying to do:

- On clicking the button, convert all the Hiragana in the table to Katakana (including the functions)
- When a user now uses this table, or types in the box, it uses Katakana
- However, I need to also keep the characters that have already been added to  as Hiragana
- And finally I need to be able to use the button again and again, switching between the two alphabets when needed

I have pretty much exhausted my JS knowledge, and would love to know what I need to do next to get this working.

Thanks.